# Анимированный фон в JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр, design

Создаю игру на JavaFX. Хочу на background меню установить анимированный фон. Я сделал его уже в mp4 и в gif формате, но как установить не знаю. Спасибо

Comment: `-fx-background-image: url( "path_to_gif" );`

Comment: Не подходит. GIF весит почти 500 МБ, не компилируется так.

Comment: 2-ой вариант: зацикленные видео в `MediaPlayer`, который находится в `StackPane` под прозрачными основными элементами.

Comment: Хм? это может и поможет. А не подскажите именно кодом? Буду благодарен

Comment: ЧУть позже попробую набросать, но крайне не уверен в хорошей производительности и в правильности подхода в целом

Comment: а как тогда можно анимировать фон меню в игре?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно уже не актуально, но раз обещал:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static final String SOURCE = "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/javafx/JavaRap_ProRes_H264_768kbit_Widescreen.mp4";

    @FXML private MediaView mediaView;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource( "sample.fxml" ) );
    fxmlLoader.setController( this );
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 600, 340 );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );

        mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind( scene.widthProperty() );
        mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind( scene.heightProperty() );

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        Media media = new Media( SOURCE );
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer( media );
        player.setMute( true );
        player.setCycleCount( MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE );
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer( player );
        player.play();
    }

}
```

*sample.fxml*:

```
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
      <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="340.0" fitWidth="600.0" />
      <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
         </padding>
         <children>
            <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Label text="Label" />
                  <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                      <children>
                        <Spinner layoutX="21.0" layoutY="99.0" />
                      </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

[image: media_bg]

P.S. Возникшие проблемы: в стабильной на данный момент ветке `Debian`( `stretch` ) на `java` версии 1.8.0_144 из коробки не завелось из-за отсутствия некоторых старых нативных библиотек, связанных с кодеками. Поэтому пришлось подключать `jessie` репозиторий и доставлять пакет `libavformat56`. Насколько я знаю, в винде проблем нет.

P.P.S. По поводу правильного подхода: понятия не имею как сделать правильно, но предполагаю, что нужно нарисовать небольшое количество фреймов( лучше использую `javafx.scene.canvas` ) и зациклено отображать с помощью `javafx.animation`.